# Unable to create a growing view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Im using the following code to animate the view when it is drawn...

```
public class MyView extends View {

    int iCurStep = 0;// current animation step

    class Points {
        float x, y;

        Points(float _x, float _y) {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }
    }

    Points[] drawPaths = {new Points(-75, 0), new Points(20, 60), new Points(60, 20)};


    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Path        path        = new Path();
        PathMeasure pm          = new PathMeasure(path, false);

        if (iCurStep <= 20) {
            pm.getPosTan(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, afP, null);
            path.moveTo(drawPaths[0].x, drawPaths[0].y);
            for (int i = 1; i < drawPaths.length; i++) {
                path.lineTo(drawPaths[i].y, drawPaths[i].y);
            }
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            iCurStep++;
        } else {
            iCurStep = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What Im expecting is that, it has to be a growing view...I mean the view has to grow as it is being drawn...But Im not able to produce to do so...How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ObjectAnimator`.

Create your view as normal, but then create an `ObjectAnimator` (docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html). You'll do something like this in your fragment or activity (you can make it in XML as well). Essentially you create an ObjectAnimator for an object with a property string. The property string must have a camelCase setter. So if you wanted to call `view.setScaleX()` as the property you were going to modify, you'd need to set the property string to 'scaleX'. Here's a simple example.

```
View growMe = new View(args);
float startSize = 1.0f;
float endSize = 2.0f;
ObjectAnimator grower = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(growMe, "scaleX", startSize, endSize);
int durationMs = 1000;
grower.setDuration (durationMs)
grower.start();
```

The one other thing you'll need to do is add an AnimationListener to your View that actually adjusts the size to be the correct as the end of the animation as (I believe--I might be wrong on this part), the view will re-size after the animation ends.

I hope that helps!

Comment: can you please explain with reference to my code because it has to follow the path

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'growing'. You want the view to 'grow' -75, 0? Does that mean the view moves 75 pixels in the x direction, the view shrinks 75 pixels in the x dimension, or the left side of the view moves 75 pixels further left?